# Is it possible to hide a particular list item of radiobuttonlist programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

I have used gridview in my aspx page.. In that I have a list with six radio buttons in a single cell aligned horizontally.

I need the 1st radio button to be hidden. How to achieve that programmatically?

```
<asp:GridView ID="CrowdRatingGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" OnPageIndexChanging="CrowdRatingGrid_PageIndexChanging" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

<PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="4" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
    Rating
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="Rating" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("rating_id") %>'
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="5" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I need the List Item with value=0 to be hidden. How would I achieve this?

Comment: If you need different logic for specific items don't use a `RadioButtonList` but single [`RadioButtons`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx). You can use a container control like `Panel` and appropriate CSS for the layout. Use the [`GroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) when only one selection is possible from a list of available options.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can hide one by setting its [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx) property to `false`:

```
Rating.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

---

Editing based on comment by OP. To completely get rid of it you'll need to do this:

```
Rating.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

and then when you want it back you'll need to do this:

```
Rating.Items.Insert(0, "0");
```

Comment: I need it to be hidden... your code just disables the radiobutton

Comment: @Coder, to do that you'll need to `Remove` it then, and `Insert` it back in when relevant.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Ok, I dug into this a little deeper and see how .NET renders the RadioButtonList control when you set it to Horizontal (it's a table with `<td>`'s for each item).

Try this:

```
var bli = Rating.Items[ 0 ];
bli.Attributes.Add( "hidden", "hidden" );
```

Comment: I need it to be hidden... your code just disables the radiobutton

Comment: Can you explain the difference you're seeing between hiding and disabling the radio button?

Comment: hiding means the radibutton will not be visible in screen... Disabling means it will be visible but cannot be checked

Comment: @Xavier - understood, I wanted to be sure that what I was seeing was the same as what Coder was seeing.  Sometimes hidden isn't always hidden in the asp.net world...  I updated my answer after realizing that my suggestion wouldn't work for what Coder wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine.

```
RadioButtonList.Items[index].Enable=True/False;
```

Ex:

```
rdTypePackage.Items[1].Enabled = false;
```

Comment: This will not hide the ListItem, it will only appear as disabled on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
radioListID.Items[index].Enabled = true/false;
```

It will work 100%.

Comment: This will not hide the ListItem, it will only appear as disabled on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, though to achieve this you can do:

```
//Ensure the item is disabled    
rblRating.Items[0].Enabled = false;
//Ensure the item is not selected
rblRating.Items[0].Selected = false;
//next row of code is hiding your radio button list item through css
rblRating.Items[0].Attributes[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListItem li = Rating.Items(0);
Rating.Items.Remove(li);
```